# Stackdriver Pricing for CloudSQL failover instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-stackdriver

How are Cloud SQL failover instances calculated within a Stackdriver premium account?

I know Stackdriver pricing is calculated per resource, and Cloud SQL instances are "chargeable ressources" as defined on the following documentation about Stackdriver pricing:

https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#chargeable-resources

But do failover replicas also count as "normal" Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: I believe a MySQL failover replica will count as a separate resource, I'll have to double check.

Comment: We also found out, that it shows up in the resource usage estimation in stackdriver, once we had a failover instance activated in a test project 
(Settings \ Resource Usage).
But I am still unsure, as right now we don't have a stackdriver premium account activated, and can't verify this behavior.